# Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Size Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, file-upload

When uploading images via HTTP I get the following array. How can I sort them by the size of the images in descending order, so the biggest size images would be uploaded the first and the smallest size the last?

```
    Array
(
    "name" => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.jpg
            [1] => 2.jpg
            [2] => 3.jpg
        )

    ["type"] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
            [2] => image/jpeg
        )

    ["tmp_name"] => Array
        (
            [0] => e7d31fc0
            [1] => qsdf0sdf
            [2] => s0sdfsfs
        )

    ["error"] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    ["size"] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20000
            [1] => 30000
            [2] => 40000
        )
)
```

As a result, the output should be as follows:

```
    Array
(
    "name" => Array
        (
            [0] => 3.jpg
            [1] => 2.jpg
            [2] => 1.jpg
        )

    ["type"] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
            [2] => image/jpeg
        )

    ["tmp_name"] => Array
        (
            [0] => s0sdfsfs
            [1] => qsdf0sdf
            [2] => e7d31fc0
        )

    ["error"] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    ["size"] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40000
            [1] => 30000
            [2] => 20000
        )
)
```

Comment: I take it that's from `$_FILES` ? Usually meaning the files have already been uploaded...

Comment: yes. It is already uploaded but not moved to my directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you will process those files in a foreach loop.

How about the code below?

```
//get files in array
$files = $_FILES['formFieldName'];
$sizes = $files['size'];
arsort($sizes); //sort in descending order but will preserve the keys
foreach ($sizes as $key => $size) {
    $fileName = $files['name'][$key];
    $fileSize = $size;
    $fileType = $files['type'][$key];
    $fileTmpName = $files['tmp_name'][$key];
    $fileError = $files['error'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Selim Mahmud's answer, I solved the solution:

```
$files = $_FILES['formFieldName'];
$sizes = $files['size'];
arsort($sizes); //sort in descending order but will preserve the keys
$files2 = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($sizes as $key => $size) {
    $files2['name'][$i] = $files['name'][$key];
    $files2['type'][$i] = $files['type'][$key];
    $files2['tmp_name'][$i] = $files['tmp_name'][$key];
    $files2['error'][$i] = $files['error'][$key];
    $files2['size'][$i] = $size;
    $i++;
}
```